# Sort accentuated characters in tableSorter 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I extract data from mysql db with query

```
select * from table ORDER BY convert(cognome using cp852) COLLATE cp852_general_ci
```

and it works correctly. 
But when user click on column *cognome* to change order Tablesorter change the collate and correct alphabetically order A, B, C, Ć, Č, Č, Đ... V, Z became wrong like  A, B, C,... V, Z, Ć, Č, Č, Đ ...
How can I force tablesorter in manteining correct collate and charset?

Comment: If you're using my fork of tablesorter, set the [`sortLocalCompare` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortlocalecompare) to `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Add these definitions to your code :

```
$.tablesorter.characterEquivalents = {
    'a' : '\u00e1\u00e0\u00e2\u00e3\u00e4\u0105\u00e5', // áàâãäąå
    'A' : '\u00c1\u00c0\u00c2\u00c3\u00c4\u0104\u00c5', // ÁÀÂÃÄĄÅ
    'c' : '\u00e7\u0107\u010d', // çćč
    'C' : '\u00c7\u0106\u010c', // ÇĆČ
    'e' : '\u00e9\u00e8\u00ea\u00eb\u011b\u0119', // éèêëěę
    'E' : '\u00c9\u00c8\u00ca\u00cb\u011a\u0118', // ÉÈÊËĚĘ
    'i' : '\u00ed\u00ec\u0130\u00ee\u00ef\u0131', // íìİîïı
    'I' : '\u00cd\u00cc\u0130\u00ce\u00cf', // ÍÌİÎÏ
    'o' : '\u00f3\u00f2\u00f4\u00f5\u00f6\u014d', // óòôõöō
    'O' : '\u00d3\u00d2\u00d4\u00d5\u00d6\u014c', // ÓÒÔÕÖŌ
    'ss': '\u00df', // ß (s sharp)
    'SS': '\u1e9e', // ẞ (Capital sharp s)
    'u' : '\u00fa\u00f9\u00fb\u00fc\u016f', // úùûüů
    'U' : '\u00da\u00d9\u00db\u00dc\u016e' // ÚÙÛÜŮ
};
```

And then add `sortLocaleCompare : true` to enable the use of the `characterEquivalents` reference

```
$("table").tablesorter({
    sortLocaleCompare : true
  });
```

Comment: Actually, the characterEquivalents definition is already existing in the tablesorter source code so not needed (unless you want to override to add/remove accents). But thanks for the sortLocaleCompare, I completly forgot we NEEDS to set it to true to apply sorting/filtering without taking care of the accented characters.